# Maven 3 Nexus - Unable to download artifacts from remote Repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a Maven 3 Nexus installed on a server. Through the Nexus GUI, I have added a proxy repository of repository policy as "Snapshot" and the URL is a remote Vendor URL, from where the artifacts/plugins are required to be downloaded. Then I have added the newly added proxy repository to the Public Repositories under Ordered Group Repositories.

Post the above activity, I have tried to build the project using mvn clean install. However the build is failing due to missing artefacts from vendor URL.

In Nexus, when I go under the Public repository and look under Browse storage, I do not see the artefact folder, which should have been downloaded from remote repository.

The "Browse remote" on the newly created repository is working fine and I can navigate to the required artifacts.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you happen to solve the issue? And, if not too late, did you configure your proxy settings for the server? Though you said you could browse the remote repository, could be something to do with proxy/ssl issues. And, what was your "Repository Status" in the repository list grid?

Answer (score 0):

If while the first run of :

```
mvn clean install
```

the required artefact was not available on Nexus, maybe it is now cache localy (on your laptop) as **not found**.

Maybe you just have to tell maven to update cache using **-U** option ?

```
mvn clean install -U
```

The other solution could be a mismatch snapshot/release repository information. Check your **Repository policy** proxy configuration on your Nexus server proxy.